# Follow some format to get data from db and fetch to another table

Tags: python, sql, rest, unix, django-rest-framework

Ok I have table call restapi information and I have a json format containing the restapi format I want to pull the data from db using sql and fetch to another table using python but I only need what is in restapi format not all the records and I also want to create a unique Id column to the same table using python can I do that? Should I use Django

SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Last_Name='Smith';

SELECT First_Name, Nickname FROM Friends WHERE Nickname LIKE '%brain%';

SELECT CustomerName, City FROM Customers; Try it Yourself »

I want to extract data from these queries to match the restapi json format which mens only what needed and fetch this values and thier names to table which calls restapi table for each value and it’s name using python

After this I want to create columns contained unique Id for each value and keep adding in case want to add anything to table later

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. No, you don't need to use Django for that!

Comment: How can I do that

Comment: Please report what have you tried.

Comment: I haven’t tried anything I need steps to do that I’m stuck I ask many but no one gives me a good answer

Comment: using sql get all the reared From table needed

2. take what is important refering to rest ali format using. SVL Command

3- Convert the resit to of using Pandas

U- write a python code to map the spacific reared to new table where each field match it's value

5. Create a python code that Jenerate unique id for each Field every time we try to add to this table

Comment: What is a `reared`?

Comment: Field’s sorry by mistake

Comment: What are "the fields from table needed"?

I think you increase your chances of having an answer if you are as much descriptive and precise as possible.

Comment: Ok I have rest api format I just need to fetch what match this format from db any information as same as what ever in json reshaping format to but in db table from Another tables unsing python